# one way connection string encryption

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, encryption

I'm looking for a web-farm friendly way of encrypting existing connection strings. Initially I decided to go for **[RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx)** which is web farm friendly and even better that it needs no existing code change as Configuration Manager automatically decrypts before passing the values.

However, they are usable only when someone has key and anyone having key can execute reverse command from command line to decrypt full file. I understand that developers with any encrypted connection string can still see plain text in debug but at least I don't want them to execute any command to convert full file to plain version (as is the case in aforesaid option).

Please suggest other similar alternates where a configuration can be encrypted one way. Even better if the code needs no change.

Answer (score 0):

One way encryption is hashing like you would use for passwords.

The original information is unrecoverable: how do you expect to be able to read the connection string?

Unfortunately, someone will always be able to read the connection string with the correct keys so you control the keys.

Is your web farm in a domain with trust to the SQL Server domain? If so, you can use integrated authentication and use a service account in the App Pool